# Need advice on customized datastructure vs using in-memory DB?

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm writing a network scheduling like program in Python 2.6+ in which I have a complex queue requirement: Queue should store packets, should retrieve by timestamp or by packet ID in O(1), should be able to retrieve all the packets below a certain threshold, sort packet by priorities etc. It should insert and delete with reasonable complexity as well.

Now I have two choices:

1. Combine a few data structures and synchronize them properly to fulfill my requirement.
2. Use some in-memory database so that I can perform all sorts of operations easily.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: How many items will the queue hold, and how large will they be?

Comment: I'm actually streaming video content for high quality video chat. The queue is used as a buffer and can grow significantly large. However with my current implementation using dicts, I haven't run out of memory.

Comment: "synchronize them properly"?  What does this mean?  A single object is your queue and that single object has a lot of methods.  What additional "synchronize" do you need beyond a class and it's methods?

Comment: By sync I meant that if I remove an element, its "indices" (for getting by ID, getting by timestamp etc) should be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A database is just some indexes and fancy algorithms wrapped around a single data structure -- a table.  You don't have a lot of control about what happens under the hood.

I'd try using the built-in Python datastructures.

Comment: Regardless of the internal data structure(s) used to implement a database, using one might be faster that a combination of built-in Python data structures because what happens "under the hood" might all be written in C optimized for the specific task. On the other hand there might be a lot of resource overhead involved if you're only using a small subset of its capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

A [Fibonacci Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) may be beneficial because (quoting from the article):

> Operations insert, find minimum, decrease key, and merge (union) work in constant amortized time. Operations delete and delete minimum work in O(log n) amortized time. This means that starting from an empty data structure, any sequence of a operations from the first group and b operations from the second group would take O(a + b log n) time. In a binomial heap such a sequence of operations would take O((a + b)log (n)) time. A Fibonacci heap is thus better than a binomial heap when b is asymptotically smaller than a.